# Read consecutive blanks in array

Tags: c

I am writing a function that reads all consecutive blanks in a string, moves the pointer to the next non-blank char, and return a struct "token" that contains the blanks it found.

The main function is defined as

```
int match_ws(const char** p, struct token* tok)
```

where `p` points to the beginning of the strings to analyze, and `tok` will contain the result after the function returns. Return value is either 1 (successful), or 0.

[EDIT]

`match_ws` starts analyzing the string given as first input, and reads all consecutive whitespaces, while advancing the pointer too. It stores all blanks it found in the struct (second input) and returns 1. If it didn't find any blank, or too many, returns 0 without modifying `tok`.

So, if the input is `const char* p = "    . +"` then after `match_ws` ran the `tok` structure will contain `lexeme = "    "` (the four spaces at the beginning of `p`, and `type = WS` (enum type for "whitespace").
If the input is `const char* p = ".   ; )"` then the function just returns `0` without modifying `tok`, because `**p` is not a whitespace (it's a dot).

Overall, this is part of a parser, and `match_ws` is the function that "consumes" all whitespaces -- not relevant for the parser. I believe the function behaves correctly, but since I am not experienced with the C language, I would like to have reviews about how I handled allocation of memory, pointer, pointer to pointers, function definition, etc.

[/EDIT]

Overall, my questions are about correct usage of pointers, pointers-to-pointers, good choice in the type of arguments (for the function definitions), and memory management.

I wrote my questions in the comments, but I am not so used to memory management and coding standards in C, so would appreciate a code review and all suggestions welcome.

I also added some boilerplate code so the file can be compiled and executed. As you can guess is part of a larger code, but I reduced it to be a minimal example.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX_LINE 100

/*
 * Some boilerplate code
*/
enum token_type {
    WS, // white spaces
    Eof
};

struct token{
    char* lexeme;
    enum token_type type;
};

char consume(const char** p);

/*
 * Main function to work on.
 * Questions:
 * - char ws[MAX_LINE] or using malloc?
 * - is it OK to initialize char ws with "" ?
 * - Am I appending char into ws in a optimal way?
 * - is it OK to return int and modify input argument tok, or should create a new tok and return it?
 * - makes sense to have pointer-to-pointer as input? Else what?
*/
int match_ws(const char** p, struct token* tok) {
    /*
     * Find all consecutives blanks starting from position p
     * Modify the input struct token.
     * Return 1 if execution was successful, 0 otherwise.
    */
    if ( **p != ' ' &&
         **p != '\t' &&
         **p != '\r' &&
         **p != '\n')
    {
        printf("Bad call to whitespace!!");
        return 0;
    }
    int i = 0;
    char c;
    char ws[MAX_LINE] = "";
    do {
        if (i >= MAX_LINE) {
            printf("Found more than %d white spaces", MAX_LINE);
            return 0;
        }
        c = consume(p);
        printf("WHITESPACE : Current char is |%c|\n", c);
        ws[i++] = c;
    }
    // Here p has been already advanced by the call to consume fn
    while (**p == ' ' || **p == '\t' || **p == '\r' || **p == '\n');
    tok->lexeme = ws;
    tok->type = WS;
    return 1;
}

/*
 * More boilerplate code to compile
*/
const char* type2char (enum token_type t) {
    switch (t)
    {
        case WS: return "WS";
        default: return "UNK";
    }
}

void print_token(struct token* p) {
    printf("<%s, %s>\n", p->lexeme, type2char(p->type));
}

char consume(const char** p) {
    // Advances the pointer while reading the input
    char c = **p;
    (*p)++;
    return c;
}

/*
 * Main.
 * Questions:
 * - is it OK to pass arguments to match_ws via '&' notation?
 * - Makes sense to have const char* line? Or just char* ?
 * - Should tok be initialized somehow?
 * - Is there anything that has to be free() eventually?
*/
int main() {

    const char* line = "     +";
    struct token tok;
    match_ws(&line, &tok);
    print_token(&tok);
}
```

Comment: I find it hard to understand the more exact outcome of `match_ws` interface to look deeper into the code. Possibly if you add some examples get a better grasp of the interface intention.

Comment: You seem to have registered with two different accounts; you'll need to flag for moderator attention to have your accounts [merged](/help/merging-accounts).

Answer (score 2):

## Answers to Questions

> - `char ws[MAX_LINE]` or using `malloc`?

The function `match_ws()` should return a pointer to a `struct token`. The token should be allocated by the `match_ws()` function, the contents of the token should also use `malloc()` to allocate the string that `token->lexeme` points to. Right now the code returns the address of a variable on the stack, this is not safe and can lead to **undefined behavior** (UB).

> - is it OK to initialize char `ws` with `""` ?

It is okay to initialize an *array* of char with `""`. To initialize a single character use single quotes instead.

> - Am I appending `char` into `ws` in a optimal way?

Using pointers would be more optimal.

> - is it OK to return `int` and modify input argument `tok`, or should create a new `tok` and return it?

See the answer to the first question.

> - makes sense to have pointer-to-pointer as input? Else what?

It would be better to use a single pointer rather than a double pointer. It is possible to corrupt the input when it is a double pointer.

> - is it OK to pass arguments to `match_ws` via '&' notation?

It is OK to pass the the token argument using the `&` notation if you don't want to allocate a token in the function, it would be better to pass `line` without the `&` notation.

> - Makes sense to have `const char*` line? Or just `char*` ?

The use of `const` is appropriate here.

> - Should `tok` be initialized somehow?

The C programming language is a very unforgiving programming language: all variables should be initialized.

> - Is there anything that has to be `free()` eventually?

Not in the current implementation.

## Don't Reinvent the Wheel

Checking the values of input characters is very common in the C programming language; a function is provided for [checking whitespace](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/isspace), and another function is provided for [checking alphanumeric characters](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/isalnum). What you do need to do is include `<ctype.h>`. The advantage of doing this is that the current code probably misses some white space characters that `isspace()` would find.

## Code Organization

Function prototypes are very useful in large programs that contain multiple source files, and that in case they will be in header files. In a single file program like this it is better to put the `main()` function at the bottom of the file and all the functions that get used in the proper order above `main()`. Keep in mind that every line of code written is another line of code where a bug can crawl into the code.